# how to show all distinct data of same original ID

Tags: mysql, sql

(Bankground: I final target is to count the number of forward citations of companies' patent per company per year.)

At current stage, I want to show all distinct PAT_PUBLN_ID which have different EARLIEST_FILING_ID in 2000, by using following SQL codes,

```
SELECT 
tls201_appln.earliest_filing_id,
distinct (case when earliest_filing_id = earliest_filing_id then pat_publn_id end)
from tls201_appln 
join tls212_citation on tls201_appln.appln_id = tls212_citation .cited_appln_id
join tls211_pat_publn on tls201_appln.appln_id =  tls211_pat_publn.appln_id
where applt_seq_nr > 0
and publn_date = 2000
group by earliest_filing_id
order by earliest_filing_id
```

But the result shows a Syntax error( missing operator) in query expression 'distinct (case when earliest_filing_id = earliest_filing_id then pat_publn_id end)'. Could you give me some suggestions about this please?

Introduction of the file: 
1.A patent application can be filed in many countries, thereby having several different APPLN_ID, and the earliest one is EARLIEST_FILING_ID.
2.There will be a published document (named as PAT_PUBLUN_ID) after patent application is filed (usually 18 months). 
3.This document recodes previous patent application which is cited as reference of this patent application. The previous patent application is CITED_APPLN_ID (which is the cited APPLN_ID）.
[image]

Comment: I don't understand your `CASE` statement.  Also, why are you using `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` in the select clause?

Comment: Sample data and desired results (perhaps simplified because your problem is probably independent from the `join`s) would really help.

Comment: Sample data can be download form here  http://webserv.epo.org/download.nsf/0/12E30309CA90A0B0C125829D004CCB61?OpenDocument

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I would like to show all distinct PAT_PUBLN_ID which have same EARLIEST_FILING_ID.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function.

Comment: thanks @jarlh, but how can I get all distinct B variables when they have same A variable? I want to list Both A variable and B variable in the table

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before you spend too much time.